# Express the first derivative as a limit of definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For a differentiable real function $f$, I would like to prove the following equation $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-1}^1\frac{3t}{2} f(x+th)\,dt.$$ I have a general expression for the $n^{th}$ derivative at my disposal: $$f^{(n)}(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-1)^{n-k}f(a+kh).$$I've attempted using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the second formula to express the antiderivative $F$ of $\frac{3t}{2} f(x+th)$ in terms of $f$, but it did not seem to work. I think I may have gotten on the wrong track, so a few hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4003449/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(h) = \int_{-1}^1 {3t \over 2} f(x+th) dt$, then
${\phi(h) -\phi(0) \over h} = \int_{-1}^1 {3t \over 2} {f(x+th) -f(x) \over h}dt$, the integrand converges uniformly to ${3t \over 2} f'(x)$ and so
$\phi'(0) = \int_{-1}^1 {3t \over 2} f'(x) dt = f'(x)$.